# Using two different versions of the same package at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, versions

I have some functions that perfectly work with ggplot2 version 1.0.1. However, the same functions do not work with ggplot2 version 2.0.0.

I think that the easier and quick fix would be use both versions at the same time. Thus, here are my questions:

1) How can I install ggplot2 version 1.0.1 and version 2.0.0 without updating 1.0.1 (i.e. having both versions at the same time)?

2) Is it possible to create a "fake name" within my system so that I can load both libraries (e.g. ggpplot2 version 1.0.1 ---> ggplot2old and ggpplot2 version 2.0.0 ---> ggplot2? If so, how could I do it?

3) Is there any easier solution than the proposed above?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,

Mario

Comment: I think better idea would be to post the functions and just make them work with the recent version.

Comment: @m-dz That might no be always possible though, imagine you wanted to interface a functionality a package no longer offers.

Comment: this is an interesting question, but is going to be an huge painXXXXX an interesting challenge, especially since a lot of function names will be identical in the two package versions and so one version will mask the other.  I suspect the easiest thing will be to download the source of the old version and hack it/do a global search and replace of the package name with "ggplot0" or whatever ...

Comment: Hi Ben, do you know how could I hack the old version?

Comment: I created another post in order to try to make the functions work with ggplot2 version 2.0.0. Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357650/ggplot2-update-2-0-0-crash-my-code-working-on-version-1-0-1

Comment: Maybe you can copy the required function(s) from https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases/tag/v1.0.1 ?